# how to convert php script to exe?

Tags: php

what is the best approach for converting php script to exe ? it should run on linux and windows.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+exe

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203100/convert-php-site-to-exe-desktop-app

Comment: -1 for a question that you seem not to have put any effort into at all to find out yourself. This is good to think about for later :) ...just makes people more helpful when it seems that you done some of your own research also.

Comment: but php is cross platform too, think about the advantage to look into the code after a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [HipHop from Facebook.](http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) This compiles PHP down to highly optimized C++ and works on Linux. You'd have to try compiling and installing it yourself, but once you got it compiled down to C++ you can now use g++ or any other C++ compiler to create for yourself a nice executable (though not .exe as it's linux only). However, since the bulk of it will be in C++ it would be easier to modify it to run on windows.

Answer (score 2):

PHP scripts already run on linux and windows, if php is installed.

Besides, what `.exe` have you ever heard of that will run on linux?

Comment: I think he'll try to write the script then run 'natively' on Linux and compiled on Win.

Comment: Besides, he can run the compiled .exe under Linux with Wine :D

Answer (score -1):

Don't think that is possible. The entire purpose of a PHP script is to dynamically produce a response to a HTTP request on a server. Whether it is an image, XML or the good old HTML page.

Why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is possible. The goal of this? Don't ask :)