# laravel executable application

Tags: windows, laravel, xampp

I have worked in one project which is built up with laravel , XAMPP Server which is replicate of desktop application created in .net

I need help regarding , how can I  convert whole thing including my laravel PHP projects, xampp server and all required files into .exe file which is stand alone for Windows application. Can anyone help me if there is anyway to make .exe file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php site to .exe desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203100/convert-php-site-to-exe-desktop-app)

Comment: No, it is not useful is there is other way of doing, or else if there is any to avoid running of artisans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible because in laravel we can make only web based applications and whereas in .net we can make both  web and desktop based applications.

Comment: i need any other way to convert.

Answer (score 0):

see PHPDESKTOP at https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop you can place the laravel code in www folder and might need to change some settings and files location to run the app.

And this repo at https://github.com/williamnwogbo/laravel_desktop contains laravel with phpdesktop.

Also there is one more project laragon https://laragon.org/ but its only a portable webserver and dbserver with additional features to add like node.js, python etc. It provides easy click interface to install laravel or php frameworks. You can explore how to use it.