# How can I create a local installation of a php app?

Tags: php, installation, local

Basically I want to know if it's possible to create a local installation of a PHP application with his own database and with the .exe bringing embedded XAMP with Apache?

So the client just executes the .exe and click next..next..next and the app has his icon and ready to use without further configuration.

Comment: you will have to write an installer

Comment: Do as @RiggsFolly said Or create a container using docker or so ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert PHP-MySQL web application to desktop app (exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203100/convert-php-mysql-web-application-to-desktop-app-exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do setup your PHP app in the Docker container. And to configure the docker app on the client machine he can use docker desktop application for mac/windows.

Once the docker desktop will be installed then he can run the app using just one docker command.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Your app will be up and running on any one machine. But if you're new with docker then set up your app in docker could be a little challenging.

Ref: https://docker-curriculum.com/